# LINQ - Strip non-distinct rows from a table

Tags: .net, linq

Trying to select distinct rows from a dt, and put the results back in the same dt. I thought this could be done in one statement. Here's what I'm trying:

```
    dt = (DataTable)((from row in dt.AsEnumerable() select row.Field<string>("VNDR_ID")).Distinct().ToList());
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I can't give you an answer in one line. There are some difficulties. First the statement above produce a IEnumerable<Row> collection and I don't know if exist any conversion to a DataTable. Second, the rows belongs to a different table and cannot be simply pasted into another table without a schema defined.

Comment: Say I wanted to select from the same table that I'd like the results to go in? Essentially stripping non-distinct rows from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    dtSuplr = (from suplr in dtSuplr.AsEnumerable()
                   select suplr).Distinct().CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ statement

```
(from row in dt.AsEnumerable() select row.Field<string>("VNDR_ID")).Distinct()
```

returns `IEnumerable<string>` not `DataTable`, so the cast will fail.

Is there a reason you need the result put into another `DataTable`?  I'd just use the `IEnumerable` returned by the query, or turn it into a `List<string>` with `ToList()` if you want the query to be evaluated immediately (so that you could change the contents of `dt`)

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast this to DataTable. The Linq will end up outputting an `IEnumerable<string>` based on your select. In order to load this into a DataTable, you'd have to:

1. create a DataTable
2. create columns with [DataColumnCollection.Add Method (String, Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/730zyedy)
3. loop through the data
4. add a new row for each item with the [DataRowCollection.Add Method (Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56)